# Sybase update column with value starting with two asterisk's in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, sybase

SQL update fails when trying to update a column with a new value beginning with two consecutive asterisk's. Using PHP with a ODBC connection to a Sybase database.

It following PHP fails without any errors or warnings:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE my_table SET my_column = '**new_value' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

However, this works perfect when the value does not start with two asterisk's.

Comment: Include your php code, that may be the issue.

Comment: The problem does not manifest its self in MySQL.

Comment: I have no idea currently for such odd behavior. ;-/ Have you tried this with a 'prepared' query?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to run this query directly, not PHP, and it works. It only fails when running in PHP. Also, it works fine when i put in 1 or 3 asterisk's, but fails when there is 2 of them.

Comment: I tested it via PHP and it works fine. Maybe it's something worng with your php or field in a table (btw I doubt it much). So share your php code with us please.

Comment: Verify the length of my_column maybe it exceeds the allowed size of the char or varchar that you are using . Also check the way query() is escaping the string.